# I split partition in Windows 7 home edition but the Windows doesn't reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, reboot

I Have Geniune Windows 7 home edition and my Laptop is Pavilion HP DV6 . I had only 1 partition of 500+ GB i Wanted to make another partition. I read somewhere in forum that I have to make my C: logical and then I'd be able to split C: I did the same thing using Partition Wizard. I made C: of 125 GB and shift rest of the space in New drive. I made a bootable disk, performed all the task using partition Wizard

After that I have not been able to boot my windows. Even after running system restore several times.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could run restore, you should also be able to get into CMD. You can fix your boot sector with `bootrec.exe`

Microsoft has an article on this issue: [Use the Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment to troubleshoot and repair startup issues in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)